# Search bib file and return article ID: editor and plugin recommendations

Tags: bibtex, citing, editors

Is there an equivalent to the Mendeley citation plugin for libre office / MS office?

I would like to insert the article ID in a `/cite{}` declaration, without having to trawl through the bib file. Instead, I would like to enter the author name or article title into a search box, be shown a list of options and then return the ID of the selected option. Is there a text-editor with a plugin that can do this?

I had a look at [this sublime plug-in](https://github.com/sjpfenninger/citebibtex), but it doesn't have the functionality that I want.

Your suggestions? Linux or Windows, either will be fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Atom and its LaTeX plugin have this functionality.

Comment: This sounds quite like [RefTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/reftex.html) (companion to [AUCTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356/105447)). And I can second [Seamus' comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides/356#comment5485_356) on how good it is.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll stat with Atom because I use it already. RefTeX sounds good too.